# Add new button in TableRow programmatically don't return the same result as XML in android

Tags: android, xml, tablelayout

There is my XML and then, there is the result of it.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/diese">


<LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

        <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1000dp" >

           <TableRow
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/one"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="1" />
            </TableRow>
```

Etc etc for tableRow.

There is the result so :

[My classic Table when i create with XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRYTm.png)

So, as we can see, i had a TableLayout into a scroll view, and each row share the available place in the table TableLayout.
Now, i add the possibility to add dynamicly some other row:

```
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(tableLayout.getContext());
    TableLayout.LayoutParams param= new TableLayout.LayoutParams(1, 0);
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(param);
    Button button = new Button(tableLayout.getContext());


    button.setId(this.idDiese);
    button.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1));
    button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    button.setText(this.intituleDiese);

    tableRow.addView(button);
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
```

And there is the result..

[When i add TableRow dynamicly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ4c4.png)

So we can notice that's new buttons doesn't take the same place that's my button in XML.
But i set to my TableRow the same layour params that's i did in my XML, and same for my buttons.

Finally, we can notice that's the style change too...

How can i do to correct this situation?

Comment: "But i set to my TableRow the same layour params that's i did in my XML" - Not quite. You forgot about the weight - the third argument - in the `TableLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: Omg, thank you so so much !!
Have you an idea for the color?

Answer (score -1):

**First you must clear one think**

> - If you add the UI components pragmatically its only shows run time. Because we just create running time.Thats why cannot add xml file.
> - Please ref [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)...